# Value that returns true on any condition?

Tags: python, variables

I have a function that loops through a large dataset. It takes multiple inputs and contains a lot of conditions. For testing, I sometimes like to run the function without certain conditions, but it is a time consuming to uncomment the conditions - which is what I do know.

Is it possible to give the function an input that always makes the condition true - both for strings and numeric values?

A simplified example:

```
def function(a,b,c....):

    .....

    item = dict(zip(header,row))
    for row in list:
        if item["variable"] == a:
            print row

    ....

    return something
```

Now I want to print any row.

`function(any,b,c...)`

I thought about giving it `item["variable"]` as input, but this does not work.

Comment: maybe `if True:`?

Comment: Give us a more complete example. Right now your code doesn't make sense. `item = dict(zip(header,row))` should probably be inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a function that returns true for any arguments:

```
def always(*args, **kw):
    return True
```

If you're looking for an object that always compares `==` to any object, you can *almost* do that:

```
class AlwaysEqual:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

But just almost—if, say, you put this irresistible force of truthiness up against an immovable object of falsity, whoever's on the left will win.

And if you want to overload multiple comparisons in ways that aren't consistent for any plausible value, like making it equal everything and also be less than everything, there's nothing stopping you. (After all, `math.nan` is not equal to anything, including itself, and that's required by standards written by people who thought it through in great detail, so Python's not going to stop you from doing something similar.)

Answer (score 1):

Split the code into 'debug mode' and 'release mode' and use explicit check in conditions. Stay away from fancy approaches as it will cause more troubles in future.

```
debug = True


if debug or len(something) > 2:
    # something always on in debug mode
    do_something()

if not debug and len(some_other_thing) > 7:
    # something always off in debug mode
    do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.

```
def function(a,b,c,test=False):

    .....

    item = dict(zip(header,row))
    for row in list:
        if test:
            print row
        else:
            if item["vaariable"] == a:
                print row

    ....

    return something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that takes a boolean and returns `True` if you're running tests, and the boolean's real value otherwise:

```py
def func(x, y, test=False):
    def _bool(b): 
        return True if test else b

    if _bool(foo == x):
        if _bool(bar == y):
            do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes instrument my programs with a comparable item, turning debug tracing off and on.  In your case, imbue each condition with a short-circuiting `or` on a flag:

```
all_true = True
# all_true = False
...

    if all_true or item["vaariable"] == a:
...
```

Do this once; you can now control it by changing the comment mark.  Perhaps more useful, you can turn it on and off during the run.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code I think you need a Python object which when you use `==` to compare it to any other Python object the result always will be `True`;

First you need to define a class the property I mentioned then use one instance of it instead of `any` to call the `function`:

```
class AnyObject(object):
    def __eq__(self, anything):
        return True

1 == AnyObject()
'' == AnyObject()
None == AnyObject()
```

Your code:

```
def function(a,b,c....):

    .....

    item = dict(zip(header,row))
    for row in list:
        if item["variable"] == a:
            print row

    ....

    return something
```

You only need to use an instance of `AnyObject` class in place of `any` when you call `function`:

```
any = AnyObject()
function(any,b,c...)
```

Now the condition is true for all the rows!

Comment: This is not practical, because then you'd need to overload every operator used in your conditionals.